# How to show that $zw=1\implies w = z^{-1}, z = w^{-1}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I need to show that

$$zw=1\implies w = z^{-1}, z = w^{-1}$$

But I don't know how to start. I've tried to consider $z=a+bi, w = c+di$ then:

$$zw = ac+adi+bci-bd\implies zw = ac-bd + (ad+bc)i = 1\implies \\ac-bd = 1\\ad+bc = 0$$

$$ac = 1+bd\\ad = -bc$$

$$c = \frac{1+bd}{a}\\d = \frac{-bc}{a}$$

$$c = \frac{1+b(\frac{-bc}{a})}{a}=\frac{1-\frac{b^2c}{a}}{a} = \frac{a-b^2c}{a^2}\implies ca^2 = a-b^2c\implies ca^2+b^2c=a\implies c[a^2+b^2] = a\implies c = \frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$$

Using $$d=\frac{-bc}{a}\implies d = \frac{-b\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}}{a} = \frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}$$

LoL I did it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Multiply both $zw=1$ by $z^{-1}$. Do the same for $w$.

Also, how do you define $z^{-1}$?

Since complex multiplication is commutative, the definition of $z^{-1}=w$ is $zw=1$. So there is absolutely nothing to prove....

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance that the complex numbers form a field then $$zw = 1 \implies z^{-1}zw = z^{-1}1 \implies w = z^{-1}.$$